# How to expand categories by id in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
org_id | person_id | month      | consultation_mode | professional_domain | number_consultations
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | in person         | doctor              | 3
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | telephone         | doctor              | 2
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | telephone         | nurse               | 1
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | telephone         | doctor              | 2
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | home visit        | other               | 4
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | null              | null                | null
```

I would like to have for each `org_id`, `person_id`, `month` a line for each category of `consultation_mode` and `professional_domain`, as per the below:

```
org_id | person_id | month      | consultation_mode | professional_domain | number_consultations
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | in person         | doctor              | 3
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | in person         | nurse               | 0
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | in person         | other               | 0
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | telephone         | doctor              | 2
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | telephone         | nurse               | 1
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | telephone         | other               | 0
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | home visit        | doctor              | 0
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | home visit        | nurse               | 0
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | home visit        | other               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | in person         | doctor              | 0
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | in person         | nurse               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | in person         | other               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | telephone         | doctor              | 2
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | telephone         | nurse               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | telephone         | other               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | home visit        | doctor              | 0
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | home visit        | nurse               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | home visit        | other               | 4
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | in person         | doctor              | 0
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | in person         | nurse               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | in person         | other               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | telephone         | doctor              | 0
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | telephone         | nurse               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | telephone         | other               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | home visit        | doctor              | 0
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | home visit        | nurse               | 0
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | home visit        | other               | 0
```

There are 3 `consultation_mode`: `in person`, `telephone`, `home visit`
& 3 `professional_domain`: `doctor`, `nurse`, `other`. How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: It is not clear by what you mean "expand". Can you add more clear detail?

Comment: Thanks @HardCode, I have just added more detail to my question, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need a small table or CTE containing the full set of consultation_mode + professional_domain combinations, then you will use a CROSS JOIN (i.e. a Cartesian product) between this table and the unique set of (org_id, person_id, month), then you will LEFT JOIN your starting table to that.

Something like this:

table raw_data:

```
org_id | person_id | month      | consultation_mode | professional_domain | number_consultations
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | in person         | doctor              | 3
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | telephone         | doctor              | 2
1      | 1         | 01-03-2018 | telephone         | nurse               | 1
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | telephone         | doctor              | 2
2      | 4         | 01-01-2015 | home visit        | other               | 4
2      | 4         | 01-12-2021 | null              | null                | null
```

table mode_domain:

```
consultation_mode | professional_domain
in person         | doctor             
in person         | nurse              
in person         | other              
telephone         | doctor             
telephone         | nurse              
telephone         | other              
home visit        | doctor             
home visit        | nurse              
home visit        | other
```

query:

```
select
    base.org_id,
    base.person_id,
    base.month,
    mode_domain.consulation_mode,
    mode_domain.profesional_domain,
    coalesce(raw_data.number_consulations, 0) as number_consulations
from
    (select distinct org_id, person_id, month from raw_data) as base
    cross join
    mode_domain
    left join
    raw_data on raw_data.org_id = base.org_id
        and raw_data.person_id = base.person_id
        and raw_data.month = base.month
        and raw_data.consulation_mode = mode_domain.consultation_mode
        and raw_data.professional_domain = mode_domain.professional_domain
/
```

Comment: Thanks @Kurt, will try it now. How can I create table mode_domain?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues can you run DDL scripts on your database or are you only allowed to query?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues I was working from the assumption that you only have this one table to work with, but see if you already have reference tables or dimensions that already exist which contain consultation_mode and professional_domain,  if it's a properly designed database, all these values should come from somehwere

Comment: I managed to created mode_domain from another table, thank you. Do you know if cross join works in hiveql? Your code is not running for me. I am using coalesce as nvl.

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues I believe so, but without knowing what error you are getting I can only guess

Comment: I think the error is related to 'base.consulation_mode' and 'base.professional_domain' - these variables do not exist in 'base' table, right?

Comment: oh right, an oversight of not having the actual tables to work with, I will fix

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks a lot!